# SMART values for brand new drive

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, smart

I'm trying to work out what SMART values I should be seeing from a brand new SSD. Having received one yesterday which is reporting quite a few power on hours (4803 = 200 days) and reboots (1136), but not that many writes (6607129448 * 512 = 3TB) I don't know what to think. The drive seems reasonably healthy from the rest of the data.

```
Reallocated Sectors Count,0,100,10,OK
Power-On Hours (POH),4803,99,0,OK
Power Cycle Count,1136,98,0,OK
Wear Leveling Count,13,99,0,OK
Used Reserved Block Count (Total),0,100,10,OK
Program Fail Count,0,100,10,OK
Erase Fail Count,0,100,10,OK
SATA Downshift Error Count,0,100,10,OK
Reported Uncorrectable Errors,0,100,0,OK
Airflow Temperature,32,68,0,OK
Hardware ECC Recovered,0,200,0,OK
UltraDMA CRC Error Count,0,100,0,OK
Good Block Rate,81,99,0,OK
Total LBAs Written,6607129448,99,0,OK
```

Comment: Print your output out and include it in your RMA request.  Send it back.  You only want to see very low values regarding power on hours.

Comment: Clearly I need to get this drive replaced but I'm still curious about what to expect from a new drive. Should all SMART values be at zero?

Comment: If the drive was picked out for random testing, it may be reasonable to expect low but non-zero values but 200 days is excessive.